# Custom clang method annotation

Tags: xcode4, clang

I'd like to achieve something like the `__attribute__((deprecated))` method annotation (`DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`), using a custom annotation for untested methods.

Is it possible to create custom annotations with Xcode 4/Clang?

What I basically want to do is have the compiler print a warning when I use a method that has a `UNTESTED_ATTRIBUTE` annotation (a method where the unit tests are still missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found no way of doing this as I'd like it to work.
Currently I'm using a deprecation attribute with a custom message:

```
#define UNTESTED_ATTRIBUTE __attribute__((deprecated("missing unit tests")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a macro like

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
#define UNTESTED_ATTRIBUTE DO_PRAGMA(message ("missing unit tests"))
```

Use it as

```
-(void)foo UNTESTED_ATTRIBUTE
```

Will emit a a compiler warning of "missing unit tests" pointing to the filename and line number

[6.58.10 Diagnostic Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)